# How to fix margin in nav

Tags: html, css

I have this code:

```css
nav li{
    display: inline-block;
    background-color:blue;
    width: 70px;
    padding: 5px;

}
nav li:first-child, nav li:last-child {
    border-radius: 5px;
}
```

```html
<nav>
        <li>Home</li>
        <li>Work</li>
        <li>Contact</li>
</nav>
```

I would like to remove this right margin.
How can I do it? I tried:

```
margin:0
padding:0
```

It doesn't work.

Comment: you want remove this spacing between nav elements or ? http://prntscr.com/6hwde0

Comment: Use the comments to connect the divs: http://stackoverflow.com/a/14776780/1654265

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's a common problem of `inline-block`s, you should remove white space between elements.

```css
nav li{
    display: inline-block;
    background-color:blue;
    width: 70px;
    padding: 5px;

}
nav li:first-child, nav li:last-child {
    border-radius: 5px 0 0 5px;
}
nav li:last-child {
    border-radius: 0 5px 5px 0;
}
```

```html
<nav>
        <li>Home</li><!--
        --><li>Work</li><!--
        --><li>Contact</li>
</nav>
```

Reference: [Fighting the Space Between Inline Block Elements](https://css-tricks.com/fighting-the-space-between-inline-block-elements/)

Answer (score 0):

Please reset of parent element `font-size: 0` and `line-height: 0` 
then set required `font-size` and `line-height` on child element
Like this way

```css
nav li{
    display: inline-block;
    background-color:blue;
    width: 70px;
    padding: 5px;
    font-size: 14px;
    line-height: 20px;
    color: #fff;
    text-align: center;

}
nav li:first-child  {
    border-radius: 5px 0 0 5px;
}
nav li:last-child{border-radius: 0 5px 5px 0;}
nav ul{
    font-size: 0;
    line-height: 0;
}
nav li:hover{
    background: #333;
}
```

```html
<nav>
       <ul>
            <li>Home</li>
            <li>Work</li>
            <li>Contact</li>
       </ul>
</nav>
```